# How do I change the odoo default port?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

In Odoo, by default the port is set to 8069, I want to change it to another port.

I've tried changing in the openerp-server.conf, the value of xmlprc, but even after restating the server, the new port doesn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution in : [How to change openerp server default](http://www.mygeekstyle.in/2013/01/how-to-change-openerp-server-default.html)

The location of the file were we can change the default port 8069 is  "server/openerp/tools/config.py" file.

I followed the instruction in the link mentioned before, but I still couldn't open Odoo with the new port until I changed the xmlprc_port to the new value in "server/openerp-server.conf". After I restarted the server, it worked fine.

#### Edit

(from comment by @danidee)

you can also change the port on the fly by starting odoo with

```
odoo.py --xmlrpc-port=8000
```

(just using 8000 as an example).

Comment: xmlrpc_port=8080 for using this parameter in config file

Answer (score 1):

In windows, edit the file:

`C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Odoo 12.0 \ server \ odoo.conf`

Change the line

`http_port = xxxx` (change the x for the port you want to use).

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to the server
2. Run command below:

sudo vim /etc/rc.local

3. Add the following lines

#!/bin/bash

/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8069
/sbin/iptables-save
exit 0

4. save and quit (wq!) from the vim editor
5. reboot server from the AWS console. (if you are using aws hosting)
6. Open port 80 in the security group inbound rules in AWS console
7. access the IP address on browser

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the xmlrpc_port key to another port in odoo.conf file.
example : xmlrpc_port = 8001

Answer (score 0):

If you use PyCharm, you can make the Run configuration like this

[image]

Or you can change the port in `odoo.conf` file. Choose one between `xmlrpc` or `http`

```
xmlrpc_port = 8000
# or
http_port = 8000
```